# Valet Install On Mac - Cannot Redeclare

Tags: php, laravel

I'm installing Valet on my MacBook Pro - El Capitan.

I installed PHP and MySQL with Homebrew as suggested on the Valet documentation page.

However, when I try to install Valet, I get the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare resolve() (previously declared in /Users/marc/.composer/vendor/hoa/core/Protocol.php:1140) in /Users/marc/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/cli/includes/helpers.php on line 57
>
> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare resolve() (previously declared in /Users/marc/.composer/vendor/hoa/core/Protocol.php:1140) in /Users/marc/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/cli/includes/helpers.php on line 57

My composer.json file looks like this:

```
{
    "require": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.2",
        "phpmetrics/phpmetrics": "^1.10",
        "laravel/valet": "^1.1"
    }
}
```

I have tried deleting composer.lock and deleted the vendor directory, then `composer install`, but nothing changes. Any one have any advice here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically there are 2 methods called the same thing, one in
`/Users/marc/.composer/vendor/hoa/core/Protocol.php` line 1140

and the other in `/Users/marc/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/cli/includes/helpers.php` on line 57.

A quick fix would be to remove the `phpmetrics/phpmetrics` dependency and run `composer install` again

Good thing is that in both places they check if the function exists, so you can declare it yourself.

If declare your own version before the `vendor/autoload.php` file is loaded, if you have control over this. So you could declare it to do what it currently does in Laravels `helpers.php`

Comment: Where exactly is this composer.json located?

Comment: @killstreet Where Valet was installed to.

Comment: I found it yeah, but this did not seem to be the issue in my case, I had to put some 'if(function_exists())' in the helpers.php file of valet but cheers anyway!

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this recently and I was able to resolve it by uninstalling / reinstalling valet:

`composer global remove laravel/valet`

then

`composer global require laravel/valet`

Comment: The problem here was this was a fresh install, and removing and reinstalling did not solve the issue

Comment: This helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I see you solved your issue, but for posterity:

You may have ran: `composer global require "laravel/laravel"`

Then ran: `composer global require "laravel/installer"`

Run: `composer global remove "laravel/laravel"` to get rid of the duplication.

Comment: Or just use something else that doesn't require me to run rings around a donkey to get it to work, which is what I ended up doing.

Comment: It's not my fault web-development == misery.